# How do I implement @params filetype into this seleciton of code?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a word search program for my Java class, and I thought I would do some research on other similar programs before I get started. (See how they work before I write my own version.)  I have stumbled across this program:

“[Java Word Search Solver](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81790/java-word-search-solver)” by [tmck-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/63431/tmck-code) via [*Code Review*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), Feb 2015.

It looks very well written, but I cannot figure out how to input my file-name for the puzzle and word list method.

Example:

```
/**
 * A method that loads a dictionary text file into a tree structure
 * @param filename The dictionary file to load
 * @return The Red-Black tree containing the dictionary
 */
private static ArrayList<String> loadDict(String filename) {
    ArrayList<String> dict = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(filename));
        String word;
        while( (word = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            dict.add(word);
        }
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        System.err.println("A file error occurred: " + filename );
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Where in this selection of code do I put my file name (`wordlist.txt`)?

Comment: You just **call** this method and provide a parameter. Something like `List<String> yourList = loadDict("wordlist.txt");`

Comment: where exactly do i type this? I'm a bit new to java, and have had some problems with methodology in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You do not put this anywhere in the code. I read a little through to code in your link. The path of your file gets passed to programm as you call it.

If you call it via a console (e.g. cmd.exe) it should look somehow like this:

```
C:\Users\yourName> java WordSearch.java "/path/to/your/file.txt"
```

You do not put anything of the information in the code itself. The programm in your link just uses the console arguments

Comment: sorry if i'm slow, but by this i assume you mean enter it into command line after executing the application, correct? I don't believe the program is designed to accept command line input, i could obviously be incorrect though. Edit: my apologizes if i'm using bad terminology, i'm in a java course in school and still have much to learn.

Comment: I mean enter it into the command line to execute it. This program especially designed to take command line input (see the `args` variable in the method called `main`). It's not even possible to run the program without command line input as far as I can see.